# Dual screen different font resolution

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, fonts, hdmi

I am using ubuntu natty and a dual screen set up with my laptop screen 1280x800 and an external monitor with hdmi connection 1920x1080 both at 60hz refresh rate. Fonts on the external screen are blurry. How can I configure them correctly?

Comment: Which is your video card?

Answer (score 1):

JUst click the menu button directly in your external screen, then go to select inputs and select HDMI PC, probably now is selected the HDMI AV and thats why you see the blurry fonts.

Oscar
Santiago, Chile.